# How to use JST namespace in generator-backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

By default (in project's grunt file) the `templates.js` file located in .tmp directory (generator-backbone), so am I missing something or this feature just don't work out of the box and I need to put additional paths in require.config?

Obviously if I will not add anything the JST will not be defined, right?

Note that I initiated the projects with Handlebars as the templating framework.

Comment: Your tag says `generator-backbone`, but your title and body say `backbone-generator`.  Which is it?  Both exist...

Comment: If you use google, then whatever variant you will put the first result is this: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - sorry for trashing SO. Obviously I've messed up paths in my `Grunt.js`.

Only `.tmp/scripts` directory is mounted and I've added `app` to the path additionally, so the files was not served at all.